# How to handle exceptions when they are used to calculate another variable?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe

```
letter       amount
a            15
b            5
c            6
d            0
e            12
```

then i use this code to see how many times a letter occured

```
try:
  a = (df.loc['a'])
except:
  print('no a in df')
try:
  b = (df.loc['b'])
except:
  print('no b in df')
try:
  c = (df.loc['c'])
except:
  print('no c in df')
try:
  d = (df.loc['d'])
except:
  print('no d in df')
try:
  e = (df.loc['e'])
except:
  print('no e in df')

amountOfTotalLetters = a + b + c + d + e
```

which gives me `name 'd' is not defined`
how do i make it so it doesn't use `d` to calculate `amountOfTotalLetters`?

I know the sum function works, but i also want to create another dataframe later in the code with:

```
data = np.array([ a, b, c, d, e])
```

Comment: you can just do `df['amount'].sum()`

Comment: also having the amount of each letter in a separate variable is very bad. You already have this info in the dataframe, or you can use a dictionary, so each letter is the key and the amount is the value `{'a': 15, 'b':5, ...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got two possibilites.
First is your approach with direct indexing. (I zipped it into a for loop to shrink the code.)

```
amountOfTotalLetters = 0
for lttr in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'):
    try:
        amountOfTotalLetters += df.loc[lttr]
    except KeyError:
        continue
```

The first solution has the advantage that you can catch the error specifically for each letter or define a general behaviour for an error, like `amountOfTotalLetters -= 10` for example.

Second is to use the implemented sum feature of `pandas`:

```
amountOfTotalLetters = df.sum()
```

or if your dataframe has many columns but you only want the sum of one:

```
amountOfTotalLetters = df.amount.sum()
```

The second approach is easier to read, faster and can be used on many columns at the same time. If you don't want to treat errors in a special way, I recommend using the second solution.

---

Concerning what you appended to your question:
There is nothing easier than making an array out of a pandas dataframe. Instead of explicit (and thus cumbersome and error-prone) `data = np.array([ a, b, c, d, e])` you can easily do this:

```
data = df.values  # If "letter" is your index
# or if letter is also a column:
data = df.amount.values
```

Answer (score 1):

`amountOfTotalLetters = df.amount.sum()`
Don't know if you're going for this tho.